# How to convert a date string "dd/MM/yyyy" format into "MM/dd/yyyy" in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert a string date formate "dd/MM/yyyy" into "MM/dd/yyyy" in c#
example

```
 string d ="25/02/2012";  i want to convert into 02/25/2012
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947423/how-to-format-date-in-asp-net

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can parse it to `DateTime` object using `DateTime.ParseExact` and later use `ToString(`"MM/dd/yyyy")`to display the`DateTime` object like.

```
string d ="25/02/2012";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// for both "1/1/2000" or "25/1/2000" formats
string newString = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Make sure to include `using System.Globalization;` at the top.

Comment: IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
                                    DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(cell.Text, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

Comment: I tried also above way its give me "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @sejalpatel, are you sure your Day and Month part is of double digits , other in parsing try `"d/M/yyyy"` format.

Comment: @Habib, if i habe both type string like "1/1/2000" or "25/1/2000" then what should i have to used?

Comment: @sejalpatel, then ` DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` this would do for both, check the edited answer as well.

Comment: @Habib whern i used below
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(cell.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Its give me error when i used date "25/02/2000" its not give me error in "1/1/2000"

Comment: @sejalpatel, it should not check again, I just checked this code: `string d ="25/02/2000";
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string d ="25/02/2012";  
DateTime dtReturn = DateTime.MinValue;

DateTime.TryParseExact(d , "dd/MM/yyyy", dateFormat,
DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dtReturn)
```

will Return "2/25/2012 12:00:00 AM"

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(your string date, "d/M/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// for both "1/1/2000" or "25/1/2000" formats
string ndt = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

use this namespace also: `using System.Globalization;`